# Create Desktop with XML

Tags: xml, desktop

Im looking for a PowerShell-command or anything other to create an xml for the desktopicons with positions on win10/11.
I can create xmls for startmenu and taskbar, but i dont found anything for the desktop.
Have anybody an idea for this? That will helps me alot.

Searching with google on forums and microsoft sites.

Comment: XML and XMLS are not the same.  XMLS is an excel file with VBA macros.  XML is not an executable. XML is a data file with just text and attributes.